# USB enclosure shows one physical drive as two drives

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, external-hard-drive, windows-10-v1607

I recently added [this 4TB hard drive](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00B99JU4S) to a usb enclosure and plugged it in.  Somehow it showed up as two hard drives in the Disk Management window [image]  I went ahead and formatted it as two drives, hoping that the situation would somehow right itself.

Any idea how this can be happening?

- It is a 4TB drive
- The system is running Windows 10 Anniversary Update
- It is in a standard USB 2.0 enclosure

How can I get the system to see the new drive as one four terabyte drive?